# Display both window AND console with pyinstaller

Tags: windows, python, cmd.exe, compile

I'm currently `using auto py to exe`, which is a program to write a pyinstaller command and execute it for you. It has two options: Console-Based & Window-Based(hide the console). However, I would like to display both. What more would I need to add to make it display both a window and console?

Current command:

```
pyinstaller -y -F -w  "C:\Users\Me\Downloads\file.py"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make it *not* window-based. That is, drop the `-w` (a.k.a. `--windowed`) option. Then your executable will start with a console attached, where all output (from the `print` function) will appear.

Having a console attached does not affect the GUI window that your application apparently *also* creates. Rather, supplying the `--windowed` option suppresses the extra console window that pops up when you run (double-click) the bundled `.exe` file on Windows. (On Linux, it makes no difference.)

Comment: Oh yeah, I wasn't waiting long enough haha! Thanks :)